# Show total count of items on page created by views

Tags: 7, views, theming

What is it right way to show total count on views?

I found this `print count($view->results);`

Answer (score 1):

You could add an element on Header, from the interface.
CLick "Add" in header section and then add a "Global: Result summary" field.

If you have to do it by code, the right variable should be:

```
$view->total_rows
```

Comment: I do not know why, but $view->total_rows do has not worked for me.

Comment: Do you have a debugger? count($view->results) works?

Comment: yes, I have. count($view->results) works.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your theme's template file:

```
function THEME_views_pre_execute(&$view) {
  if ($view->name == "MACHINENAME_OF_VIEW") { // can also check for display if need be
     $view->get_total_rows = TRUE;
  }
}

function THEME_views_post_execute(&$view){
  if ($view->name == "MACHINENAME_OF_VIEW") { // can also check for display if need be
     $view->attachment_before .= <div class="result">$view->total_rows</div>
  }
}
```

The first function enables getting the total rows if you do not have a pager set. The second adds it to attachment_before. Attachment_after is also available.

Comment: it does not work/